# Rails eager load where field matches the parent's field?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, models

I'm trying to eager load a model where I try to eager load a single record.

Let's say:

```
Customer.includes(:sales).where('sales.created_at' => 'customer.last_sale_at')
```

but instead of working SQL WHERE:

```
... WHERE "sales"."created_at" = "customer"."last_sale_at"

 count 
-------
  1990
(1 row)
```

rails produces invalid:

```
... WHERE "sales"."created_at" = 'customer.last_sale_at'

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "last_sale_at"
LINE 1: ...d" = "customers"."id" WHERE "sales"."created_at" = 'last_sale...
```

I also tried:

```
Customer.includes(:sales).where('sales.created_at' => '"customer"."last_sale_at"')
Customer.includes(:sales).where('sales.created_at' => :last_sale_at)
Customer.includes(:sales).where('"sales"."created_at" = "customer"."last_sale_at"')
```

which produced variety of errors.

What's wrong?

**EDIT**: I updated the question to be more self-explanatory.

Comment: Is last_sale_at is date object you passed in condiion?

Comment: it is field in model I'm eager loading from.

Comment: In the `WHERE` clause I self-refer to `customer` model's `last_sale_at` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call conditions when using "includes" because the records are being eager loaded in a separate query. You need to use a join instead:

```
Customer.joins(:sales).where('sales.created_at = customers.last_sale_at')
```

That being said, I suggest you use a slightly different architecture where you you create an actual relation on customer that points to the last sale, I.E a foreign_key 'last_sale_id'.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sales
  belongs_to :last_sale, class_name: 'Sale'
end
```

When a sale is created you can update the customers last_sale in a callback:

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :update_customers_last_sale

  private

  def update_customers_last_sale
    customer.last_sale = self
    customer.save!
  end
end
```

With that structure you can do this to load all customers with their last sale:

```
Customer.includes(:last_sale)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to rails and didn't know there's .joint().
FYI only: The `last_sale_at` is here only to know when the user made their last sale, for the sorting sake. I wanted to also be able to get link to that last sale. I was able to, but rails ran n unnecessary queries per customer and I wanted to eager load it as well.
Well, thank you again for your time. Your answer is really apperciated :)

Comment: you can specify conditions on eager loading check this out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations

Answer (score 1):

You should pass date object instead of 'last_sale_at', it should be something like below,

```
Customer.includes(:sales).where('sales.created_at' => Time.now)
```

Comment: But I need the sale at the time that is stored in customer's `last_sale_at` field. See updated question...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your error

`ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "last_sale_at"`

It clearly states that there's a syntax error in your query. Active record is expecting it to be of date time as your *sales.created_at is a timestamp* and you are suppling it as a *string or some other type which is not of datetime type*. You need to pass in a date object to get your query working.

**FIX**

You need to make sure that your *last_sale_at* field is of `datetime`

Comment: It is datetime, problem is in the where clause. I need the sale at the time that is stored in customer's `last_sale_at` field. See updated question...

Comment: The thing is Rails should produce `... WHERE "sales"."created_at" = "customer"."last_sale_at"` but instead I get `... WHERE "sales"."created_at" = 'customer.last_sale_at'` which is nonsense. The reference is to own field in `customerController`.

Comment: @lmojzis what is the type of last_sale_at in your db?

Comment: @lmojzis if you look at rail guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations, it should work. Don't have anything to test on right now though